# Spring REST and real world object graph

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I've read this spring-data-rest tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ and I can't see how this can be applied in a real world situation where we don't have just one object, but a graph of objects.

Let's say that we have an Order object which has one-to-many relationship to an Item which is categorized by a Category object. Let's say for the sake of it, that the Category is implemented in a tree-like structure (so it has a parent and some children; i.e. an Electronic category could have 2 children, Computer and TV, the former having another two children, motherboard and keyboards).
And let's say that all these relation are two ways (i.e. an Order can see it's items and an Item can access it's Order)

So when I request an Order object threw my REST service, I'm gone  get the Order, all it's Items and each Item will have the whole graph of Category which will be linked to each Item and thus all the orders. So I'm basically returning the whole database.

I do understand that the bidirectional relations is not ideal but even if we suppress the many side of the relationship, when requesting an Order, we would still get 
Order-Item-Category-Parent Category-Parent of Parent Category-etc...

So how do you stop a graph of objects being serialized?

Furthermore, you might not want to break the graph at a fix point.
For instance when I request an Order, I might want to see it's items and the category of each item, but definitely not the parent's category.
However, when I want to explicitly display a Category, I would then like to see it's parent. Get it?

Does somebody have some insight for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is where DTOs are a good thing. :)

You build the object structure you need and return it via json. You have full control over this structure, you dont have bidirectional relations and you can just give that back as an object graph from your controller.

Another (good) side effect is that you decouple persistence and view completely. I.e both can evolve independently.

One (negative) side effect can be the increased maintenance. You have, at least, twice the classes to maintain and also the mapping in between. Frameworks like `Dozer` can help you with the mapping at least.

---

Another solution can be to implement some addons for `Jackson` that handle all these cases without the need of DTOs. 
I myself created the Antpath filter to dynamically decide which path to filter out in Jackson: 
https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

But you will need some more things to consider if you like to work with domain entities directly.

- cycle breaker (to avoid bidirectional relations for example)
- lazy loading / open session in view pattern as the serialization can go everywhere
- hibernate proxies which have method which are not serializable (session)

Comment: DTO! that was exactly what I hope I could avoid. I totally agree with everything you said about them: full control, decoupling and unfortunately BIG increase in maintenance